# GRUB rescue after deleting linux from HDD

Tags: grub

I have SSD and HDD in new laptop. By default linux (EndlessOS) was installed on HDD. After successfully instaltion Windows10 on SSD I tried to delete data from HDD by GParted, then when I rebooted I get error like:

```
error: no such device: ostree.
error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I tried use boot repair from windows recovery, but it didn't change anything.

**EDIT: I also tried issue these commands:**

```
>bootrec /fixboot
The operation completed successfully.
>bootrec /fixboot
The operation completed successfully.
>bootrec /rebuildbcd
Scanning all disks for Windows installations.

Please wait, since this may take a while...

Successfully scanned Windows installtions.
Total identified Windows installations: 1
[1] C:\Windows
Add installation to boot list? Yes(Y)/No(N)/All(A):yes
The requested system device cannot be found.
```

But, last command doesn't complete properly.